# How do I wait for an actor to stop during Play Framework shutdown?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2

The below code throws a **java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException** exception when I shutdown the play server; it is caused by the **a.wait(1000)** call in the **onStop** method. Could anyone tell me why this is the case and how to gracefully wait for an actor to complete within Play framework shutdown?

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import akka.actor.{ Actor, Props }
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.Play.current
import models.{ TestActor, StartMessage, StopMessage }

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

    override def onStart(application : play.api.Application) {
        val a = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "test-actor")
        a ! StartMessage("Start instruction")

    }

    override def onStop(application : play.api.Application) {
        val a = Akka.system.actorSelection("akka://application/user/test-actor")
        a ! StopMessage("Stop instruction")
        a.wait(1000)
        Akka.system.shutdown()
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the complete solution, taking the below answer:

```
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import akka.actor.{ Actor, Props }
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.Play.current
import models.{ TestActor, StartMessage, StopMessage }
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration
import scala.concurrent.Await
import com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext
import com.typesafe.config.impl.ResolveContext
import akka.actor.ActorIdentity

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

    override def onStart(application : play.api.Application) {
        val a = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "test-actor")
        a ! StartMessage("Start Instruction")
    }

    override def onStop(application : play.api.Application) {
        val a = Akka.system.actorFor("akka://application/user/test-actor")
        a ! StopMessage("Stop Instruction")

        try {
            val stopped : Future[Boolean] = gracefulStop(a, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(5, "seconds"))
            Await.result(stopped, scala.concurrent.duration.Duration(6, "seconds"))
            // the actor has been stopped
        }
        catch {
            case e : akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException => // the actor wasn't stopped within 5 seconds
        }

        Akka.system.shutdown()
        Akka.system.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Comment: You might find this article useful: http://letitcrash.com/post/30165507578/shutdown-patterns-in-akka-2

Answer (score 7):

"Graceful Stop
gracefulStop is useful if you need to wait for termination or compose ordered termination of several actors:

```
import akka.pattern.gracefulStop
import akka.dispatch.Await
import akka.actor.ActorTimeoutException

try {
  val stopped: Future[Boolean] = gracefulStop(actorRef, 5 seconds)(system)
  Await.result(stopped, 6 seconds)
  // the actor has been stopped
} catch {
  case e: ActorTimeoutException ⇒ // the actor wasn't stopped within 5 seconds
}
```

"

- http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/scala/actors.html#Graceful_Stop

PS. Googling for "graceful actor akka" gives the answer as the top result.