# akka system.shutdown and awaitTermination

Tags: akka, jruby, shutdown

Following code is called at the very end of my program (it's written in JRuby):

```
@na.tell(PoisonPill) if defined? @na   # @na, @sa and @pe are Actors
@sa.tell(PoisonPill) if defined? @sa
@pe.tell(PoisonPill) if defined? @pe

@@system.shutdown    # @@system is the ActorSystem
@@system.awaitTermination
```

I found this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412869/how-do-i-wait-for-an-actor-to-stop-during-play-framework-shutdown) but I don't understand why it works.

Does `awaitTermination` wait for all Actors to terminate?

Isn't `@@system` shutted down before `awaitTermination` is called?

**edit:** I noticed that I doesn't even need to call `tell(PoisonPill)`. I commented it out and it still works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it now. When I call `system.shutdown` all actors terminate after their current task. That's not what I want because there could be more tasks in the queue.

So I send a PoisonPill to each actor at the end of my main thread and then wait for them to terminate. I also use the function `postStop` in each actor to set a `finished` flag and shut down the `system` when all actors have finished.

```
import Actors   # needed for Java-style poisonPill

actor1.tell(Actors::poisonPill)  # for Akka 2.0.0
actor2.tell(Actors::poisonPill)
system.awaitTermination
```